# Javascript - Image.complete is true, but returning false in Firefox when running real time

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

I have a function:

```
function IsImageLoadable(URL) {
  var imageObj = new Image();
  imageObj.src = URL;

  var x = (imageObj.complete);
  var y = (imageObj.naturalHeight);

  if ( (x === true) && (y !== 0))
    return true;
  else
    return false;
}
```

The problem is that in Chrome, IE, Edge, and Opera, this functionalty works correctly. If the image is loadable the `x` and `y` variables are set to `true` and some number bigger then 0 accordingly. However, in Firefox ran in real time, `x` and `y` are set to `false` and `0`.

The reason I say real time is because when debugging and stepping through line by line, `x` is equal to `true` and `y` is equal to 500ish.

Is this an issue when using image objects in Firefox? Any suggestions?

Comment: Where your handler for onload event?

Answer (score 1):

Set handler on load Image

```
function IsImageLoadable(URL) {
  var imageObj = new Image();
  imageObj.src = URL;

imageObj.onload = function(){
   //your code
}
}
```

Comment: I agree that the event handler is another way to do it (probably the preferred way by most, but I'm trying to avoid it). Do you have any idea of why Firefox is offering this behavior?

Comment: @FrankPalmasani I do not know maybe it's specification engine Gecko and his work with pictures. Maybe he does not have time to process the data to give you the result immediately.

Comment: interesting. The reason I avoided using call backs is because I'm using the results of IsImageLoadable to make decisions and the events are asynchronous.

Comment: In vain it is now gaining popularity reactive programming. In Angulyare in reagent and so on. I think it is not necessary to give it up)